# Solve this riddle, don't be a flake!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I probably won't blind you, but it certainly won't be pleasant
>   The merger of a leader and global mass supporters
>   Oft followed doubly by a joint and a set of ten

What am I?

Hint:

> The last clue is only missing some key facial features

Hint 2:

> Each line refers to a somewhat different definition of the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> Head & Shoulders (Shampoo brand)

I probably won't blind you, but it certainly won't be pleasant

> Getting shampoo in your eyes isn't nice, Head and Shoulders is especially painful

The merger of a leader and global mass supporters

> Leader (Head) + supporters (Shoulders) (reference to idiom Carrying the weight of the world on your shoulders)

Oft followed doubly by a joint and a set of ten

> (Intended Answer) Reference to Head Shoulders Knees (joint) and Toes (set of ten) the children's rhyme
>  (Original answer) You have a head on your shoulders which is followed by a joint (elbow) and a set of ten (10 fingers)

Hint:

> The rest of the rhyme is Eyes and Ears and Mouth and Nose

Comment: This is the correct answer, though your explanation for the last clue is wrong, and the your explanation for the global mass supporters is a bit off

Comment: I bet Eyes and Ears and Mouth and Nose would help, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're

> a flame coming out of a lighter.

```
I probably won't blind you, but it certainly won't be pleasant
```

> Looking directly at the flame of a lighter tickles the eye, without hurting much.

```
The merger of a leader and global mass supporters
```

> Maybe related to using a lighter in a concert

```
Oft followed doubly by a joint and a set of ten
```

> The flame can be used to light up a joint, around a set of teens.

Comment: Nope sorry, not the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Are you...

> A hand?

I probably won't blind you, but it won't be pleasant.

> A slap to the face, maybe?

The merger of a leader and global mass supporters

> A leader (elbow) and global mass supporters (fingers)

Oft followed doubly by a joint and a set of ten

> Joint (elbow) and a set of ten (10 fingers, with 5 fingers on each hand)

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer I am looking for, but you are kind of warm on the last hint

Answer (score 2):

Are you....

> A smart phone screen, displaying facebook specifically?

I probably won't blind you, but it certainly won't be pleasant

> checking your screen at night isn't literally blinding, but quite unpleasant, especially with the facebook color scheme

The merger of a leader and global mass supporters

> A smart phone could connect a public figure with all of their followers through social media, especially through facebook

Oft followed doubly by a joint and a set of ten

> Hitting the "follow" button on the screen by moving some joint in your body, with your ten fingers "following" as in being next to or behind, the screen. The phone's screen can also be referred to as its face, and "facial features" could be a nice hint towards additional facebook "features" or functions other than following.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

SECOND TRY!

Is it an...

> arm? The answers to the hints are the same.

Comment: You should edit your existing answer if the reasoning is all the same.